# CSS preprocessor/library for centering and fills

Tags: css, frameworks, mixins

I have barely used anything other than vanilla CSS but would really like to do a couple things that aren't working well now:

I have an inner border inside a div, which I want to actually border the inside of the encapsulating div's border (double border). However with window resizing, the inner border will sometimes have too large/small width/height, even when using a measurement like % or vh/vw. I need the inner border (just a div with a border right now) to always stretch/shrink to fit snug right next to the parent border.

Similarly (notoriously) with centering, I imagine there must be a library with the ability to easily center elements vertically and horizontally. Generally I use flex box but would love something that works more consistently, elegantly and intuitively.

What say ye?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're talking about a CSS framework, they help out a lot, especially when working on a major project. I would check out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/), I personally use [mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/), which is a 3rd party hybrid of the two.

Comment: Do Bootstrap or Material Design have the ability to solve both the problems I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, both of them do :).

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Tacit](https://yegor256.github.io/tacit/) a try for this particular need.

Tacit is a class-less CSS framework were all you need is just a single `<link>` statement in your HTML and the web page will have a complete and finished look.

The centering of elements vertically and horizontally come out of the box, and you can skip the usage of `<div>` elements or the work of defining classes for your elements.

As a side note, here are a few examples of pages that use Tacit, and the only work put into was including the CSS file: http://filfreire.com/, http://www.jare.io/, https://socatar.com/